# Iterating through a Panda dataframe to count and adjust a cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration, python-3.7

I have a Panda's dataframe like so:

```
        colLabelA   colLabelB   ... colLabelZ
rowLabelA   10      0           0
specialRow  0       10          0
rowLabelB   20      0           10
...
rowLabelZ   0       0           20
```

Essentially I only know the row called `specialRow`.  What I need is to find a way to iterate through the entire dataframe and check all the columns for 0 (zero).

If a column has all zeroes except `specialRow`, then that column by row cell needs to be made into a zero as well. Otherwise move to the next column and check that one.

So in the above example, only colLabelB has all zeroes except the `specialRow` so that needs to be updated like so:

```
        colLabelA   colLabelB   ... colLabelZ
rowLabelA   10      0           0
specialRow  0       0           0
rowLabelB   20      0           10
...
rowLabelZ   0       0           20
```

Is there a quick and fast way to do this?

The dataframes aren't huge but I don't want it to be super slow either.

Comment: Is that `specialRow` an index value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `drop` to drop the named row, then check for `0` with `eq(0).all()`. Then you can update with `loc`:

```
df.loc['specialRow', df.drop('specialRow').eq(0).all()] = 0
```

This works with more than one special rows too:

```
specialRows = ['specialRow']
df.loc[specialRows, df.drop(specialRows).eq(0).all()] = 0
```

Output:

```
            colLabelA  colLabelB  colLabelZ
rowLabelA          10          0          0
specialRow          0          0          0
rowLabelB          20          0         10
rowLabelZ           0          0         20
```

Answer (score 1):

For each column, exclude the particular index, then check if all other values for that column is zero, if yes, then just assign `0` to such columns:

```py
for col in df:
    if df[df.index!='specialRow'][col].eq(0).all():
        df[col] = 0
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
            colLabelA  colLabelB  colLabelZ
rowLabelA          10          0          0
specialRow          0          0          0
rowLabelB          20          0         10
rowLabelZ           0          0         20
```

In fact `df.index!='specialRow'` remains the same for all the columns, so you can just assign it to a variable and use it for each of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the row with 'specialRow', check if column's values are all zero.

```
if (df.drop(['specialRow'])['colLabelB'] == 0).all():
    df['B'] = 0
```